# What class options make a good ranged and melee striker?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation, optimization, striker

What I'm looking for is a Striker, who is mainly a ranged striker, but also, sometimes, can go melee. As obvious. Something like an Arcane Archer or whatever would you call it. I've read a lot of guides and stuff, yet I found nothing astonishing.

Now what I'd like are these things:

- Stealth, Perception, Bluff and Insight are vital for my gameplay, if I'd be left with more to pick, it would be athletics OR acrobatics, depending... and the last heal.
- The next thing I'd like to have would be a few spells, don't have to be combat spells, but shouldn't be rituals.
- Also, I wouldn't like to use poisons as a main or important part of my class and I don't really like shields.
- I prefer bows and swords, but that's not really an issue.
- I don't like simple pew-pew style, need some more options. Someone suggested to me a Ranger with Battlefield Archer PP, but I'm not really sure how to work with that.
- It can be hybrid, doesn't have to be... whatever. Any race. Level 12, as I said.

Is this too much to ask or is there something that would allow me to do all or at least most of these things and still have a reasonable damage output?

Comment: Have you looked at the hunter build for rangers from Martial Power 2 (not the Hunter class from D&D Essentials)? Also, you could look at the Hexblade (from D&D Essentials).

Answer (score 11):

First, you need to tone down your expectations. There aren't any strikers that are ranged & melee *and* use weapons & spells *and* get boatloads of skills (correction: there aren't any that actually do decent damage). But if you're willing to give up the spells part...

It sounds like what you want is a ranged rogue. The focus on ranged powers will mean you're most effective at range, but pull out a dagger and you're perfectly happy in melee. Also, you get training in your entire wishlist of skills (well, you have to pick athletics *or* acrobatics, but other than that you're set) plus thievery as an added bonus.

There are 2 general builds I'd recommend looking at: a typical halfling sling rogue ([this guide](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/29060077/Han_Shot_First%3a_A_Scoundrels_Guide) can walk you through building it), or a bluffing multi-attack build (the core concept is described [here](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/28936427/Heather,_Alluring_Rogue_%28Changeling_Escaped_Slave_RogueArena_Champion%29)) which will only do mediocre (though never *bad*) damage until level 16, at which point it will do *very* good (arguably broken) amounts of damage.

*Alternately*, you could give up the striker part and go with a bow-wielding bard. Ranged spells & bow attacks, plus some melee attacks (though you'd need a way to swap weapons as a free action; I'd recommend a familiar) covers your ranged/melee request. You'll have to burn a feat to get stealth, but you get insight, perception, bluff, and acrobatics/athletics by default, plus arcana.

If you go this route, I'd recommend going half-elf, wis/cha heavy, Virtue of Prescience, and grabbing Twin Strike as your Dilettante power, along with Versatile Master and the multi-class feat that makes your Dilettante power use your class' primary attribute for attacking instead of dex. [This guide](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/21106285/Cruel_Lullabies%3a_The_Bard_Handbook) can walk you through building the character.

Answer (score 3):

After some experimenting with the Dungeons and Dragons Character Builder I think I've found what you're looking for. It's not perfect, but I think a Hexblade (player essentials 2) is best suited for your needs. The description given in the character builder is as follows "Roll: striker. You wield a deadly weapon forged with magic, backed by your skills at spells, stout armor, and keen fighting ability." This class is fairly flexible, with multiple builds. I suggest making charisma your primary attribute and dexterity your second, since you are so keen on the skills affected by dex and cha.
                                                                                             This leaves you with 3 compatible race choices- Halfling (+2 acrobatics, +2 thievery), Drow (+2 intimidate, +2 stealth), and Changeling (+2 bluff, +2 insight). To make the most of your skills in and out of combat I suggest playing a Changeling. Changeling Disguise allows you to change your appearance (as long as you remain humanoid) at will, giving you a +5 to bluff checks made to conceal your identity. Changeling Trick is a combat skill that can give you combat advantage until the end of your next turn if you manage to make a successful bluff check against your target's passive insight.

The powers available to Hexblades are very versatile, allowing for ranged and melee combat. Hexblades choose one pact. I personally enjoy the Star Pact (Dragon Magazine #393) which grants the Dire Fate power the most. Once per round, as a free action, if you reduce an enemy to 0 hp or an adjacent enemy falls to 0hp you gain a +1 bonus to attack rolls until the end of your next turn. As a striker more accuracy always comes in handy.  Aside from your melee basic attack, all of yhe Hexblade's melee attacks come with neat effects. You may be able to teleport into a better position or deal extra damage to a nearby enemy on a successful hit. If you get tired of swinging your sword around you can throw a couple of Eldritch Bolts or unleash a powerful daily power. The most intimidating of which is Hellfire Blast (player essentials 2) which unleashes a close blast 3 exlposion (great for crowd control) dealing 3d8 + cha modifier damage. Plus half damage on a miss.

To sum everything up, you can engage in close combat or pick off your enemies from a safe distance, destroy hoards of monsters with large and powerful blasts, and use your character's rougeish tricks to gain the upperhand in battle. You'll be able to train several of the skills you're looking for.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! one minor quibble, minions don't die on misses.

Comment: Wax Eagle: Normally they wouldn't but becaise Hellfire Blast does half damage on a miss, it's like a gauranteed hit. Instead of hitting or missing, you do more damage or less damage. Since minions only have 1hp, this will instantly kill them. Thank you for the welcome! :)

Comment: Kaori: Minions don't take damage on a miss. *Period*. What that means is that when a power says it does damage on a miss, minions ignore that damage. Auto-damage (damage that doesn't require an attack roll) will guaranteed kill minions, but attacks that do damage on a miss will not.

Comment: Oblivious Sage: Oh wow! I had no idea. I'm definitely going to start minding that rule. I supose it's good to give minions some staying power. Also, I went back to the character builder to see what I could do about all of the skills he wanted. Hexblades are unable to train Acrobatics, Athletics, and Perception. I suggest training stealth, bluff, insight and either intimidate or theivery. Assuming that the character is a changeling, the skills will be 8, 12, 6, and 10 or 8, respectively. I assume changeling because it will give you a boost to insight.

Comment: For a bit more insight you can choose the background Birth: Blessed (Player's Handbook 2) for another +2 insight, which will make your score 8. And if you are really keen on more skills, you can always take a multiclass feat. Acolyte of the Veil will give you acrobatics training and the Shadow Step assasin power. Bardic Dilettante allows training in one skill from the Bard class set (perception is in there) and the Majestic Word power for some handy heals. Depending on your GM's rules regarding magic and enchanted equipment there are tons of items that can give you a skill bost as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have a character that does something like this.
Hengeyokai Thief, goes around with a frost hand crossbow, a Spellsoul blade rapier, and a couple daggers. Two Fisted Shooter lets you use the crossbow efficiently. Use the frost cheese combo for CA, and several items give you bonuses with cold damage. The Thief gives you a TON of skills, and with the right feats, you can boost those to ridiculous heights. He will be stuck with only melee basic attacks, but that just means you get to role play the description of your attacks.

My Rogue at level 16 has these stats as his normal attack once the frost bonuses get added:
Rapier - 26 VS AC/REF | 1d8 + 24
Crossbow - 25 VS AC | 1d6 + 22
Target is guarantied to have at least 5 vulnerability to cold, so you get +5 to those on top. So, very high damage, both melee and ranged, lots of skills (I have 7) and you get to role play a ton.

Notes:
Hengeyokai is my pick, for the alternate form (rat is fun to role play) but halfling, human, and a couple others also do great.
I also use the gloves of Ice, and dragon-shard augments for more damage.